# What are the main power draws within a mobile phone radio?

Tags: power, radio, modulation

It is often quoted that "3g uses more power than 2g on voice calls" or other similar things, but it seems from a theory perspective that transmitting low bandwidth voice data with a high bandwidth protocol like UMTS, HSDPA etc. with more spectrally efficient modulation should use less energy than transmitting the same data over an older standard network like GSM which has less spectrally efficient coding, lower data rates, and longer timeslices.

Rumour is that the majority of the power in new protocols is not used in the actual emitted radio waves, but instead in the electronics that process, amplify and modulate the signal.  Is this the case?  Are there any public studies/numbers to back this up?

Thanks in advance,
Oliver

Answer (score 2):

Very nice  study.

Slides:

[An Analysis of Power Consumption in a Smartphone](http://www.usenix.org/event/atc10/tech/slides/carroll.pdf)

[PDF of same](http://www.usenix.org/event/atc10/tech/full_papers/Carroll.pdf)

[image]

Conclusions:

- Major consumers:

  display & cell radio

  WiFi power low in most situations

  CPU can be significant

  Future power driver
- Where power is not going:
- RAM
- Audio
- Bluetooth
- Storage

---

Korean study.
 [27 slides](http://www.ekc2011.org/II-05.-%20EKC%202011%20-%20Smartphone%20power.pdf) -  results differ somewhat from above.

---

[Energy tradeoffs in smartphone apps](http://enl.usc.edu/papers/cache/Ra10a.pdf)

\

Comment: Interesting study, although I was wondering what specifically _within the radio_ uses power - rather than other power consumers within the phone.  I suspect finding data on that is harder because it can really only be collected by a radio chipset manufacturer...